# How to reject fetch promise in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, isomorphic-fetch-api

Hi there I using fetch like this:

```
export function fetchSomething() {
  return ({fetch}) => ({
    type: FETCH_SOMETHING,
    payload: {
      promise: fetch('/someUrl', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400)
        {
          let error = new Error(response.statusText);
          throw error;
        }

        return response;
      })
    }
  });
}
```

If that fetch return invalid json the whole promise will be rejected and _ERROR action dispatched - no exception will be throw. Instead of exception it emit PromiseRejectionEvent.

If however response code is >= 400 then exception is throwed and also _ERROR action is dispatched.

How can I emit that event and reject promise when checking status code without throwing an exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem. I am using [Bluebirdjs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) instead of default browser Promise.

And for fetch I was using [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) which use their own Promise library, so even if I have registered:

```
window.Promise = require('../common/configureBluebird');
```

the isomorphic-fetch used something different.
So I switched to [fetch-ponyfill](https://github.com/qubyte/fetch-ponyfill) which by default uses window.Promise as Promise and now it is working.

So if I throw new Error() in then(), it will catch automatically and emit event [PromiseRejectionEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseRejectionEvent)